# how to add dynamic field in magento2 admin form

Tags: javascript, admin, magento2

I want to implement dynamic Form field in magento2

in which user can add as much as images as per requirement just like add more option ,

I have implemented this by adding 10 new images on edit but user is not able to add more images on the way

after form i have written this

```
$newfieldset = $form->addFieldset('new_fieldset', ['legend' => __('New Images #')]);
    foreach (range(0, 10) as $newid) {      
    $newfieldset->addField(
        "newimages_$newid",
        'image',
        ['name' => 'galleryimages[]', 'label' => __('New Image #'.$newid), 'title' => __('New Image #'.$newid), 'required' => false ,  'disabled' => $isElementDisabled]
    );
}
$this->setForm($form);
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

let me know if this can be done more Dynamic just like on click a button **Add Image** new field is added in form

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a js function to generate the files that you need, i think you can use this function to add an script block to the form:

```
$this->setChild('form_after',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Vendor_Company::folder/js.phtml'));
```

and you can create a script to add dynamic fields via javascript

```
<script>
    require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/adminhtml/form", // in case you need some of the magento functions
    'domReady!',
], function ($) {
     //YOUR CODE HERE ...
});
```

I hope this solution hepl you, i don't know if is the correct way, but this works